# Chrome debug tooltip having scrollbars

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

There seems to be a scrollbar permanently in the tooltip when I hover over variables in Chrome's debug view. This makes debugging very difficult.  I have installed the latest Chrome update, but the problem persists:

[image: This is how it looks like].

How can I remove this scrollbar?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: It's on Windows.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I had the same problem and found your post. I went as far as reinstalling Chrome, but to no avail. The solution for me was to change the zoom size of the developer tools window. This can be done using ctrl+/-. I guess I was at a smaller zoom size than was natural, and finding the original 100% zoom fixed this problem for me. 'Hope that helps!

Comment: This issue was resolved in later updates of Chrome.

Comment: This issue is still present for me ( 49.0.2623.112 m )

Comment: And for me 49.0.2623.112 m, Windows 7

Comment: And for me 51.0.2704.103 Win10.

Comment: i zoomed out and it fixed my problem

Comment: I had the same problem today. @Yahya still the same with todays latest version - Version 53.0.2785.101 m

Comment: @OgnyanDimitrov I never saw that issue again after the update in March.

Comment: Ctrl-0 resets the zoom

Comment: I have the same issue, even after resetting the zoom to 100%. The issue the OP stated only clears if I zoom to around 120%, but then the rest of the text in the dev tools is obviously huge, which gives me a different problem!